# How to provide object method as callback of requestanimationframe function?

Tags: javascript, oop

I am using requestanimationframe function of javascript and also i created a object in javascript. I want to use method of my object within requestanimationframe function as callback.

syntex : requestanimationframe(callback);

And I try : requestanimationframe(this.rander); not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to call it from another function, and use a temporary variable to get the reference to `this` :

```
var self = this;
requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    self.rander();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try requestAnimationFrame(); *case matters in javascript*
2. Also make sure this function is supported in your browser : `requestAnimaitonFrame = requestAnimationFrame || webkitRequestAnimaitonFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;`

Comment: I am using requestAnimationFrame() in my code as well but not working. so it may not be issue of case matters.And Aslo i use latest mozilla firefox. it is working when i pass non object function in requestAnimationFrame()

Comment: @VLAS Funny how you give him crap about case but then mess up the name of your impromptu-shim 'requestAnimaitonFrame' ???